# Best way to check every data point inside dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames contain 110.000 rows and 10 columns and another with 47.000 datapoints with 8 columns. I use the 2 dataframe to check the validate of first DataFrame. If this match, i will take this row of first DataFrame and second DataFrame to new DataFrame.

The way i check is inside the 2nd DataFrame i got a `keyword` in column keyword. Then i check this with column string of 1st DataFrame if it include keyword or not.

Now i'm using `2 loops iterrows()` to check it. But i will take a lot of day to do. I wonder is there any more efficient way to do this. 
My code is like this :

```
    for index, ebayrow in ebaydata.iterrows():
        make_match = [e_scrubrow for idx,e_scrubrow in etail_scrub_data.iterrows() if e_scrubrow['keyword'] in ebayrow['title']]
        nummatch = len(make_match)
        if nummatch == 0:
            continue
        else:
            model_match = [e_scrubrow for e_scrubrow in make_match if e_scrubrow['keyword2'] in ebayrow['title']]
            nummatch = len(model_match)
            if nummatch == 0:
                continue
            else:
                if nummatch == 1:
                    scrubrow = model_match[0]
                    ebaychecked.append(scrubrow['keyword'])
                    ebaychecked1.append(scrubrow['keyword2'])
                    ebaychecked2.append(scrubrow['keyword3'])
                    ebaychecked7.append(ebayrow['info'])
                    print(len(ebaychecked))
                else:
                    year_match = [e_scrubrow for e_scrubrow in model_match if e_scrubrow['keyword3'] in ebayrow['title']]
                    nummatch = len(year_match)
                    if nummatch == 0:
                        scrubrow = model_match[0]
                    ebaychecked.append(scrubrow['keyword'])
                    ebaychecked1.append(scrubrow['keyword2'])
                    ebaychecked2.append(scrubrow['keyword3'])
                    ebaychecked7.append(ebayrow['info'])
                        print(len(ebaychecked))
```

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far

Comment: I have edit my question above